# Android: save LinkedList in method OnSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, save, instance, state

i'm new to android development and i'm facing this problem:

How can i save the state of a linkedList in the OnSavedInstanceState method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`LinkedList` is `Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html), so long as the list contains other `Serializable` objects, you can use `putSerializable()` and `getSerializable()` on the saved instance state `Bundle`.

That being said, using `LinkedList` is rather unusual. You may be better served using `ArrayList`, in which case you also have the option of `put...ArrayList()` and `get...ArrayList()` methods for various data types (e.g., `String`) along with anything that is `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.